# Laravel get data base on user input between two dates column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.8.

I have a reservation model that contains a start_date and an end_date. The user chooses a month from a dropdown list say April (04).

I would like Eloquent to return all records where the month is between the boundaries of the start_date and end_date columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I finally got it to work. Thanks to everyone who contributed.

```
$month = request()->month; // from the dropdown list
$reservations = Reservation::where(function ($query) {
        $query->whereMonth('end_date', '>=', $month);
        $query->whereMonth('start_date', '<=', $month);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
  $from = Carbon::parse('first day of April 2020');
  $to = Carbon::parse('last day of April 2020');
  $reservations = Reservation::whereDate('start_date', '>=', $now)
                               ->whereDate('end_date', '<=', $to)
                               ->get();
```